# How to delete stashes as a batch?

Tags: windows, git, atlassian-sourcetree, git-stash

How can I delete some of my Git stashes at once? I tried in sourceTree, but it seems I can only delete one stash at a time. Can I delete several of them at the same time? Is there a command to do this in git bash? I don't want to delete all of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Bash [Brace Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html), we can create a long list of stashes quickly, e.g., `stash@{8} stash@{7} stash@{6} stash@{5} stash@{3} stash@{1}`

can be made with `echo stash@\{{8..5}\} stash@\{{3,1}\}`

Putting together with `xargs`, or a `for` loop, we get:

```
echo stash@\{{8..5}\} stash@\{{3,1}\} | xargs -rn1 git stash drop
```

**Note**: the list must be reversed.

Answer (score 1):

This should do:

```
echo -e 'stash@{6}\nstash@{3}\nstash' | xargs -rl git stash drop
```

But make sure to "count down" as the commands are executed one after the other and if you use the numeric reference like in my example after each command the indizes would shift so start with the oldest. Or of course use its name that you gave when saving.